# Vimperator (Firefox) macro to copy text

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, vimperator

I am using Vimperator 3.8.1 with Firefox 25.0. I have created a macro to solve a problem (details below), and this macro fails at the following point.

Vimperator Macro `e`:

```
/foo<Return>cv<Down>y
```

My macro searches for a string (`'foo'`) in the page, then goes into caret mode, then into the visual mode, and then selects one line of text and then copies that text.

My problem is that when I record this macro, the one selected line gets copied, but when I play it (using play command), nothing gets copied onto the clipboard. Thus, due to this, I am unable to retrieve that info in an automated manner. I don't know what to Google for in this case, so I posting this here on SO.

I will be highly obliged if someone can also explain why this happens the way it does. Please also let me know if something is not clear.

**Problem Details**

I am using Vimperator 3.8.1 with Firefox 25.0. I have a lot of tabs (about 300 tabs) which contain similar information (only one line is different on each tab). I want to copy that single line from each tab and collate it in one place. That one line begins with the string `'foo'` in every case, and each of the 300 tabs has links that can be incremented using Ctrl+a in Vimperator (i.e. ...page=1, ...page=2)

How I plan to accomplish this is as follows. I have an online notepad open in tab 1, and the very first of my 300 tabs open in tab 2. I copy my single line from tab 2, and paste it into tab 1, then go back and increment tab 2 to point to the next tab. I will repeat this macro 300 times to get all the info.

Thus my complete macro will look like

```
/foo<Return>cv<Down>y<C-PageUp><C-t>p<C-PageDown><C-a>
```